# WPF ListView - how do i set selected item background colour?

Tags: wpf, listview, background

I currently have this, but it only work for the foreground colour.

Any help would be apriciated :D

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/> 
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will take care of the background color, maybe it will also help you find the solution for the foreground, this is from http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I had to fix your xml a bit :D The </Style.Triggers> should be </Style>

Answer (score 1):

It is the [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) sub-element of the ListViewItem named "Bd" which handles background painting.

```
<Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="Green" Property="Background" />
```

Comment: Then i get "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter." error.

Comment: Move it to ControlTemplate.Triggers inside the Style.