# Default Style ListBox / ListView / ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: xaml

I would like to know what setters I have to change in XAML to remove the default style when you select an item in any collection like(listview/listbox/combobox).

By default it's blue,but I didn't want any visual aspect cause my listbox contains a stackpanel of objects and I didn't want a blue background around the item if the user click just next to the stackpanel.

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this post :
[WPF ListView - how do i set selected item background colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153345/wpf-listview-how-do-i-set-selected-item-background-colour)
and this MSDN blog post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx

If you want to change the style of the selected item, just define this style, and you can set the same style for the selected items and the other items :

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

The HighlightBrushKey and HighlightTextBrushKey are the styles used when the listview has the focus, ControlBrushKey and ControlTextBrushKey when an other control has the focus.